# RobotC upload sound file to EV3

Tags: robotc

I am now working with the EV3 and would like to upload a sound file to the EV3 using RobotC. I already converted some .WAV files to .RSO files and pasted them to this folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Robomatter Inc\ROBOTC Development Environment 4.X\EV3 System Files\Sounds
```

Then I tried to play the file on my brick but nothing did work.

```
setSoundVolume(30);
playSoundFile("Luigi.rso");
```

I also tried it by clicking on "Download Firmware", but that didn't work, either.

One more thing I tried is to upload the file directly to the brick, so I opened **Robot -> LEGO Brick -> File Management Utility** There I tried to *Download* this "Luigi.rso" file and so the file is now in the **/home/root/lms2012/prjs/rc** folder. The file exists, because this script displays the **Big smile**:

```
bool bExists = bEv3FileExists("Luigi.rso");
if(bExists)
{
    drawBmpfile(0, 127, "Big smile");
} else
{
    drawBmpfile(0, 127, "Black eye");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EV3 sound file extension is .rsf, not .rso. Try changing the extension, as follows:

```
playSoundFile("Luigi.rsf");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the .rso. If that won't work, press F1 in robotc, that opens the help viewer.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer - it is incorrect, untested, and suggests that the OP consults Help in the program instead of answering the question. Please don't post an answer if you don't have one.